# Javascript form validation

Tags: javascript

I'm wondering, Is there a JavaScript command (whats the proper name for the thing im looking for?) where I can select all input boxes in a form rather than just one?

E.g:

```
 function checkform(id){
var theForm = document.getElementById( id );
if (theForm.surname.value == '') {
  alert( "you didn't type in your surname");
  theForm.surname.focus();
  return false;
}
else if (theForm.surname.value.length == 0) {
  alert( 'You\'ve left some of the fields blank' );
  theForm.surname.focus();
  return false;
}
return true;
}
```

I have this code. The purpose of it is that it checks each input box in the form to see if information has been entered, and if it hasn't, an alert appears when the user submits the form.

Is there a way I could change this piece of JavaScript in order to check every input box and not just the surname one (as seen in the example).

Answer (score 0):

The method `getElementsByTagName` can give you all the inputs, the `elements` property will hold a NodeList of all the controls in a form.

```
var nodeList = theForm.getElementsByTagName('input');
```

or

```
var nodeList = theForm.elements;
```

Comment: No. The former will only get inputs, it won't get, for example, `select` elements.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need the `document.getElementsByTagName()` method for this one. You could link this up with your current function like so:

```
var inputs = document.getElementsByTagName('input'), // get all input tags in the document
    i = 0, // set counter to zero
    l = inputs.length; // get number of inputs you have found
for (i; i < l; i += 1) { // loop through the inputs you have found
    checkform(inputs[i].id); // send the id of each input to the `checkform` method
}
```

Of course you might want to rewrite the function you have to make it more efficient, but you could potentially drop this straight into your code (outside the `checkform` function) and it should do what you want.